# Three-tier application

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I've got a problem with a project client-server-database. I've written the client application in Java SE (GUI: Swing). Hibernate will be provided communication between the server and the database. I do not know, however, how to realize the communication between the client application and server application, which in fact I have not yet.

-The first idea is to write a server application in Java SE and the use of RMI protocol for remote server methods invocation by the client.
-The second idea is to write application server in Java EE, using EJB + eg. JBoss.

The problem is, I do not know how to achieve the second idea, because I had no contact with this before. At this point, I have got a few questions:

1. Which idea is more reasonable?
2. Which idea is faster?
3. In the case of the first idea, I read that the web server is used to dynamically delivered classes. Do I need to use the web server if I will predict all the necessary classes and I will put them locally?
4. What with aspects such as multithreading (access to the server + access to the database by multiple clients at the same time) / security? In the case of the second idea, I have to take care of these aspects yourself?
5. Could you give me an example a client and a server implementations for the second idea? How to connect, how to call a remote method with parameter transfer by the client, etc.

Comment: my "gut" feeling would be to follow the j2ee path, AFAIK, it's capable of supporting RMI, but more importantly, it can provide a web service, along a far more flexible solution in the long run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Which idea is more reasonable?

It depends on your topology. RMI is a good choice for single-machine topology, and can even work well across LANs; but it has limitations which make it [poorly suited for the Internet](http://dev.root1.de/projects/simon/wiki#Why-SIMON-is-better-than-).

Of the two ideas you presented, if your client is distributed over the Internet, JavaEE is more reasonable. There are other viable choices as well, such as [Typesafe Activator](http://typesafe.com/community/core-tools/activator-and-sbt), a lightweight non-JavaEE application server which supports Web services.

> 2. Which idea is faster?

RMI has the simplest and most compact serialization, so it will always be slightly faster. However, this is a relatively unimportant concern, unless your application is extremely chattery, and even then it's still unlikely to outweigh good design.

> 3. In the case of the first idea, I read that the web server is used to
>      dynamically delivered classes. Do I need to use the web server if I
>      will predict all the necessary classes and I will put them locally?

In both cases you will want a client-side object representation of server-provided data, and in both cases you will want to keep those data classes in sync between server and client. So this isn't a particularly useful differentiation.

> 4. What with aspects such as multithreading (access to the server +
>      access to the database by multiple clients at the same time) /
>      security? In the case of the second idea, I have to take care of these
>      aspects yourself?

Correct. JavaEE provides solutions for those concerns whereas RMI doesn't.

> 5. Could you give me an example a client and a server implementations for
>      the second idea? How to connect, how to call a remote method with
>      parameter transfer by the client, etc.

This request is far too involved for an answer here. Besides, tutoring is outside the scope of StackOverflow. The best I can do is advise you to either hire a JavaEE professional, or to find a JavaEE book and start studying! :)